# What shock mount setup is being used in this picture?

Tags: microphone, shotgun

I was doing some research before purchasing some audio recording equipment, and came across this interesting combination that I can't quite identify: [image: shotgun microphone with foam filter mounted inside a shock mount]

From this 2016 video:

(interestingly, this setup never appears again in more recent videos by the author)

I'm fairly confident the microphone is a Sennheiser MKH 416, with possibly the stock foam filter, shoved into a universal shock mount (?). For some reason I like the way this looks, but it seems ill advised to use this shock mount setup rather than a shock mount specifically designed for shotgun mics. Am I correct in my assessment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is true for every mic/mount combination, but definitely the weight of the mic needs to be balanced by the 'springiness' of the mount.

If they're mis-matched it doesn't work so well.

From a recent question on this site, I tried jamming a $3,000 U87 into a $3 shock mount from a cheap Chinese mic.
It looks kind of OK, but it rings like a bell if you so much as breathe on the mic stand.
Totally useless sonically. It's quite a bit better with its own mic in there.

I'd stick to the mount made for the mic you choose.

[image]

If you were wondering why it's battleship grey rather than shiny brushed steel, it's a BBC-spec U87 from the early 80s. They didn't do 'shiny' for Auntie Beeb.

Oh… in answer to your **actual** question, I haven't the foggiest idea, but it doesn't look well-suited to that application.